# jQuery Toggle different links

Tags: jquery, animation, toggle

I need your help. I am trying to add some animation to click event. I could this very easily with toggle, but my problem is, i have 2 buttons with different names and styles, and i need when one is clicked the other shows and the button clicked hide. Here is my code so you can understand it better:

My markup is only 2 links:

```
<a href="#" class="show-more"><?php print t('Show more'); ?></a>
<a href="#" class="show-less"><?php print t('Show less'); ?></a>
```

Can anyone help me on this? I need help putting this working with animation (like a jQuery toggle is fine) and advice for performance. Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

http://jsfiddle.net/jYnnc/

**NEW UPDATE**

I find a way to reproduce what i need, here is the code:

```
$('.user-profile .resume p').each(function() {
    var $obj = $(this);
    var height = $obj.height();
    var maxHeight = 40;

    if (height > 40) {
        $obj.css('height', maxHeight).css('overflow', 'hidden');
        $obj.siblings('.show-more').show();
    }

    $obj.siblings('.show-more').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $obj.animate({
            'height' : height
        }, function() {
            $obj.siblings('.show-more').hide();
            $obj.siblings('.show-less').show();
        });
    });

    $obj.siblings('.show-less').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $obj.animate({
            'height' : maxHeight
        }, function() {
            $obj.siblings('.show-more').show();
            $obj.siblings('.show-less').hide();
        });
    });
});
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PCR8W/1/) with this last code.

Can anyone help me improving this code? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Could you post a working example in a fiddle, as your question doesnt make the problem clear. My guess is that it would be better to have one button and change the function based on whether the relevant div is visible/hidden.

Comment: Post your `HTML` or create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: Thanks for your answers, i updated the initial post with jsfiddle.

Comment: Here is other fiddle just to see the effect/animation that i need, http://jsfiddle.net/9HyEq/ . In this example i used a toggle, its more easy, but how can i get the same effect on the fiddle in the first post?

Answer (score 0):

If your question is about how to show one when clicked second with some animation,
this could be your solution:

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sky8V/

Hope I helped :)

JS

```
$('.show-more').click(function(){
    $('.show-more').hide('slow', function(){
        $('.show-less').show('slow')
    });
});

$('.show-less').click(function(){
    $('.show-less').hide('slow', function(){
        $('.show-more').show('slow')
    });
});
```

CSS

```
.show-less { display: none; }
```

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="show-more">Show more</a>
<a href="#" class="show-less">Show less</a>
```

Comment: Hi @jave.web thanks for your help, no it's not what i need, i don't need the buttons to hide/show with animation, the animation should be on the content (p) not the buttons/links. Maybe my question was not so clear.